# Line by Line compare Left Indent greater than or equal to the line before it - VBA MS Word Macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

Here's my working code for anyone that needs it in the future.

```
Sub Test()

Dim prePara As Paragraph
Dim curPara As Paragraph
Dim nextPara As Paragraph
Dim i As Integer

For i = 2 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

    Set prePara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i - 1)
    Set curPara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i)

    'in case i need this variable later.
    If i <> ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count Then
        Set nextPara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i + 1)
    End If

 'I use heading styles for formatting. If it's not the style I'm using it's probably these. I wouldn't want my entire doc to sequentially indent off of each other   
    If curPara.LeftIndent <= prePara.LeftIndent And curPara.Style = "Normal" Or curPara.Style = "List Paragraph" Then 

        ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i).Range.Select 'selects the active paragraph
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) = False Then 'makes sure it's not a table
            If curPara.LeftIndent < prePara.LeftIndent Then 'if the current paragraph's indent is less than the one before it then...
                curPara.LeftIndent = prePara.LeftIndent 'make the indent equal to the one before it
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next


End Sub
```

### --------------

I'm a newer coder, sorry if this seams trivial.

I'm trying to create a macro that goes throgh each line and makes sure that any line that has an indent of 0 has an indent greater than or equal to the indent of the line before it. If it is not greater than or equal to the line before it, I want the indent to be equal to the previous line.

I've found Selection.Paragraphs.LeftIndent is the code that I need to work with but I'm not good at constructing simple code like this without an example of how to do it. I was thinking a "For each oPara In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs" loop but unsure on how to actually code it. 
I was just thinking that this only applies to text that is not "Heading 1"

```
Dim Para As Object

For Each Para In .Paragraphs

If Para.Paragraphs.LeftIndent = 0 and para.Paragraphs.style <> "Heading 1" Then
   'get paragraph indent of the previous paragraph
   'If then comparitive indent statment
       'make the current paragraph = to previous Para
   'End If
End If
Next
```

### dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/22523394/Indent%20Example%20.docx

Update new code based on below...

And I'm very frustrated and lost...this code is terrible and I don't know where to go with it. It doesn't even remotely structurally look like it's goin to accomplish my task.

```
Dim prevParagraph
Dim currentParagraph

'Use the first item in the list as the first 'prev'
Set prevParagraph = List(1)

'Now, starting with the second item, go through the rest of the list
For i = 2 To List.Count
'Get the current item
Set currentParagraph = List(i).Paragraphs.LeftIndent
Set prevParagraph = List(i - 1).Paragraphs.LeftIndent

If List(i).Paragraphs.LeftIndent = 0 And List(i).Paragraphs.Styles <> "Heading 1" Then
'Finally, make sure to use the current as the prev for the next iteration of the loop


End If
Set prevParagraph = currentParagraph
Next
```

---

Newer Code...still bad but better?

```
Dim prevParagraph
Dim currentParagraph
Dim list

' Use the first item in the list as the first 'prev'
Set prevParagraph = list(1)

'Now, starting with the second item, go through the rest of the list
For i = 2 To list.Count
'Get the current item
Set currentParagraphIndent = list(i).Paragraphs.LeftIndent
Set prevParagraphIndent = list(i - 1).Paragraphs.LeftIndent

If currentParagraphsIndent = 0 And list(i).Paragraphs.Styles <> "Heading 1" Then
'Finally, make sure to use the current as the prev for the next iteration of the loop
    Selection.Paragraphs.LeftIndent = prevParagraphIndent
End If

Set prevParagraph = currentParagraph
Next
```

---

Here's a concept from scratch. I just don't know if this would work of the verbage to make it work.

```
For Each Paragraph In Documents.Active
If currentParagraphs.LeftIndent = 0 And currentParagraphs.Style <> "Heading 1" Then
    If previousParagraphs.LeftIndent > currentParagraphs.Indent Then
        Selection.currentParagraphs.Indent = previousParagraphs.LeftIndent
    End If
End If
currentParagraphs = previousParagraphs
```

### Next

```
'here's my newest code that works out ish, i need to tinker with it.

Dim prePara As Paragraph
Dim curPara As Paragraph

For i = 2 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count

    Set prePara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i - 1)
    Set curPara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i)

    If curPara.LeftIndent <= 0 Then
        If curPara.LeftIndent < prePara.LeftIndent Then
           curPara.LeftIndent = prePara.LeftIndent
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Were you able to get it? :D

Comment: I wasn't able to get to it today. Another project took over for today. I'll get back at it tomorrow.

Comment: I tried...and I got to an object requred error. I thought I had it.

Comment: I'm an idiot..."AvtiveDocument" is not "ActiveDocument"...it works but needs some tweeking that I'm working on, for instance ignoring tables is something that I want it to do.

Comment: One thing you should probably add to your code is, up at the top, `Option Explicit`.  This will cause VBA to give you an error when you try to use a variable that hasn't been explicitly declared - it REALLY helps prevent accidental spelling mistakes from causing hard-to-diagnose errors later.

Comment: I thought it was on by default. Also I made another question regarding this code. I don't know the propper etiquite with when should I ask another question so I did. If you're interested here's the link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23633209/need-script-to-ignore-msword-tables-probably-a-simple-issue-with-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of situation happens a lot in Computer Science - the need to go through a list of things and keep track of the previous one.  Here is some pseudocode to give you an idea of how to handle this:

```
Dim prev
Dim current

'Use the first item in the list as the first 'prev'
Set prev = List(1)

'Now, starting with the second item, go through the rest of the list
For i = 2 To List.Count
    'Get the current item
    Set current = List(i)

    ' ...
    'Do stuff comparing prev to current
    ' ...

    'Finally, make sure to use the current as the prev for the next iteration of the loop
    Set prev = current
Next
```

If this doesn't fully answer your questions, drop a comment below.

---

I didn't want to give you the full code because of course it's much better for you in the long run to understand what's going on, but here's what I would try, line for line (Ignoring "Header 1" for the moment), if it was me:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim oPrevPara As Paragraph
Dim oCurrPara As Paragraph


'Use the first item in the list as the first 'prev'
Set oPrevPara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1)

'Now, starting with the second item, go through the rest of the list
For i = 2 To ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count
    'Get the current item
    Set oCurrPara = ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(i)

    ' ...
    'Do stuff comparing prev to current
    If oCurrPara.LeftIndent = 0 Then
        If oPrevPara.LeftIndent <> oCurrPara.LeftIndent Then
            oCurrPara.LeftIndent = oPrevPara.LeftIndent
        End If
    End If
    ' ...

    'Finally, make sure to use the current as the prev for the next iteration of the loop
    Set oPrevPara = oCurrPara
Next
```

Does that help?

Comment: I'm not getting it. I added my code that I'm trying to type at the bottom of my post. I'm going to need some more help.

Comment: The code I gave you is pseudocode, meaning "prev" "current" and "list" are just placeholder names to demonstrate the concepts.  In your case, you would want to create two variables, `Dim oPrevPara As Paragraph` and `Dim oCurrentPara As Paragraph`, and your list would be `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs`.  You can refer to individual paragraphs in the active document by number using `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(n)`.  For example, the first paragraph is `ActiveDocument.Paragraphs(1)`.  Try using the pseudocode above, but use your variables.

Comment: The other thing you should know is that you can compare the indents without needing temporary variables.  For example, you can compare the current indent to 0 with the following boolean statement (assuming your variables are named as I suggested): `oCurrentPara.LeftIndent = 0`.  You can compare them to eachother like so: `oPrevPara.LeftIndent > oCurrentPara.LeftIndent`.